# how query multiple siblings in xml - but not all

Tags: xml, siblings

I know how to select all the sibling nodes of a parent element and I know how to select only one.  But, what if there are five and I want to select just two or three by name?  For example, given this sample xml fragment:

```
<book id="bk101">
   <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
   <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
   <genre>Computer</genre>
   <price>44.95</price>
   <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
   <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
</book>
```

How would I select nodes BOTH title and author?

I can get title by using /book/author and title by using /book/title but how do I combine them into one query like I would a SQL query:  SELECT Author, Title from Book?

There must be something similar, no?

Comment: The xml sample is not displaying correctly, I will try to post again here:

Comment: <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>

Comment: Is this an XPath question? If so, which version?

Answer (score 1):

In XPath 2.0: `book/(author|title)`

In XPath 1.0: `book/author | book/title`

Comment: Thank you.  Both syntaxes worked perfectly.  Sorry for such a basic question, but I couldn't find an example anywhere and I looked at quite a few sites.  Can you tell me for future reference where I should look for an answer like this?  (Thanks again for the swift response)

Comment: You could read the W3C specs, or you could read my book *XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 Programmer's Reference* 4th edition (Wiley/Wrox)